# SQL Azure privacy issues

Tags: sql, azure, privacy

I only starting to learn about SQL Azure, have spoken to some potential clients, they say they have not chosen Azure due to the private nature of their customers information.

Reading about Azure it has firewalls to prevent unauthorised access.

I was just wonder what other way I could market Azure so that clients who potentially want to use it would not be concerned about privacy issues.

Also as I understand Azure supports Hybrid solutions where you can store data locally or remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Azure is a public service and the data is stored somewhere in the cloud provider facility. With all security measures including firewalls and sentry dogs the data is still under zero customer control.

So the provider could do some backup and store it for some very long time and you might want to destroy the data ASAP and will be unable to have it done.

Also here's what technically *could happen* (not that I'm saying it is likely):

- the provider might dispose of undestroyed hard disks
- a bug could cause the authorization to fail and allow an unauthenticated user (because you see, you don't control what software updates the provider applies)
- the provider employee might be bribed and copy the data

So if the user really wants privacy (or the laws say the data he deals with must be processed according to certain requirements) or he wants actual control on how the data is dealt with then a public storage service like SQL Azure is technically inapplicable for him. You trying to market Azure as providing the same level of control and security as a local facility would provide are deceiving the customer.

Sad but true and *you can't lie to the compiler*. There's no such thing as control over your data in a public storage service. Risks of negative outcomes are perceived as rather low, but they exist and they are real.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [Azure service bus](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/service-bus/) has connecting private and public clouds as a feature. Keeping sensitive data locally may be what your clients want/need to push parts of their infrastructure to the cloud, although it will take some effort for sure to keep that separation clear, and I'm not just talking technically.

That said, marketing Azure to a client that's not ready for the cloud may very well lose you the entire deal, so make sure you're not pushing anything *they* aren't ready to cope with to start with.

Comment: If I want my data to be stored locally I'll have to do the processing locally as well. How do I make use of a public cloud then?

Comment: @sharptooth You could for example anonymize data (an example would be to replace any identifiable info not needed in the calculation itself with Guids), pass it to the cloud, process, pass it back and reconnect the info to the correct local info. Another way would be to do just statistical, already anonymized calculations there, like sales trends/predictions. It all depends on the level of security needed.

Comment: I see. Yes, that will work in many cases, but not in all cases and also requires some extra processing which can be a problem when the dataset is really big.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is the [Windows Azure Trust Center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/) to learn about Windows Azure privacy and security.

There's also a 7-part Windows Azure security best practice series on the ISV Developer Community Blog. [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2012/03/07/windows-azure-security-best-practices-part-1-the-challenges-defense-in-depth.aspxa) has links to the remaining entries, at the end of the post.

Microsoft's data centers are run by [Global Foundation Services](http://www.globalfoundationservices.com/), which has its own set of [security and compliance](http://www.globalfoundationservices.com/security-and-compliance.aspx). There you'll find a [data center tour video](http://cdn.globalfoundationservices.com/videos/Video_Data_Center_Long_Tour_8000k.wmv)